# Postback a page based on webmethods result

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback, webmethod

How can I post back to a page based on result of WebMethod ?

```
 function AssignmentConditionsSaveAS_Clicked() {

        var txtConditionName = $('input[id$="txtConditionName"]').val();
        PageMethods.IsExistsSavedCondition(txtConditionName, OnSuccess, OnFailure);
        return false;
    }

    function OnSuccess(result) {
        if (result == 'true') {
            if (confirm('A saved condition with that name already exists. Do you want to overwrite?')) {
                return true;
                // I want to post back the clicked button
                // Can not use __dopostback, because its a control inside a user control                    
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (result == 'false') {
            alert('Not Exist');
        }
    }

    function OnFailure(error) {
        alert(error);
    }
```

OR

How can I do somehting like this:

```
__doPostBack($('input[id$="btnSaveAS"]'), '');
```

Comment: or $('input[id$="btnSaveAS"]').click() ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to do this

```
__doPostBack($('input[id$="btnSaveAS"]').attr('name'), '');
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you just need to get the button and call the click() function to do the post back.